# amazon S3 or EBS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created Amazon EC2 instance to host mvc.net developed application. Now I have an requirement where I need to store images for my resources.which is best place to use store images and how to fetch them during runtime? Amazon S3 or EBS ? how to do it. please help me

Comment: A very similar question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2288402/1129593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have architected solutions on AWS for Stock photography sites which stores millions of images spanning TB's of data, I would like to share some of the best practice in AWS for your requirement:

P1) Store the Original Image file in S3 Standard option

P2) Store the reproducible images like thumbs etc in the S3 Reduced Redundancy option (RRS) to save costs

P3) Meta data about images including the S3 URL can be stored in Amazon RDS or Amazon DynamoDB depending upon the query complexity. Query the entries from Amazon RDS. If your query is complex it is also common practice to Store the meta data in Amazon CloudSearch or Apache Solr.

P4) Deliver your thumbs to users with low latency using Amazon CloudFront.

P5) Queue your image conversion either thru SQS or RabbitMQ on Amazon EC2